# How to convert these 2 methods into generic methods?

Tags: java, generics

Hello i have the follow two methods

first

```
public ObjectId getObjectIdByRegionName(Region region) {        
        Query<Region> query = datastore.createQuery(Region.class);
        query.field("R_NAME").equal(region.getName());
        return query.get().getId();
    }
```

second

```
public ObjectId getObjectIdByNationName(Nation nation) {
        Query<Nation> query = datastore.createQuery(Nation.class);
        query.field("N_NAME").equal(nation.getName());
        return query.get().getId();
    }
```

how could i turn them into generic method?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
public <T> ObjectId getObjectByName(T name)
```

Or add them to an interface or class that uses generics:

```
public interface LocationDao<T extends Nameable> {
    ObjectId findByName(T location);
}
```

So now you'll need something like this:

```
public interface Nameable {
    String getName();
}
```

As noted in the comments, you need to have a parameter that has a `getName()` method.  You'll need a restriction to make that true.

Comment: Agreed - that's the next step.

Answer (score 2):

Although duffymo's approach is preferable (cleaner etc), if you don't have control over the source for your parameter classes (or you can't impose interfaces etc), you could just do this:

```
public <T> ObjectId getObjectIdByNationName(T param, String name, String fieldName) {
    Query<T> query = datastore.createQuery((Class<T>)param.getClass());
    query.field(fieldName).equal(name);
    return query.get().getId();
}
```

or even this non-generic version (since you can do without type scoping):

```
public ObjectId getObjectIdByNationName(Object param, String name, String fieldName) {
    Query<?> query = datastore.createQuery(param.getClass());
    query.field(fieldName).equal(name);
    return query.get().getId();
}
```

It would however mean some duplication by the caller to call with the field name and the name every time. If each parameter type is only called from one location, there would be no duplication.

Comment: +1 - yes, this seems like a good solution too, if you don't want to create a separate interface.